# Best practice reading file as InputStream

Tags: inputstream, dart

In Dart, I want to read BMP, so could be BIG file.
I do it like this :

```
var inputStream = imageFile.openInputStream();
inputStream.onData = () {
  print(inputStream.available());
  inputStream.read(18); // Some headers
  int width = _readInt(inputStream.read(4));
  int height = _readInt(inputStream.read(4));
  // Another stuff ...
}
```

It works well with little image but when I a read a 3Mo file, the onData is executed many times. Indeed, the onData is trigged by 65536 bytes packets.
What the best practice ?
Should I write a automat with state like HEADER_STATE, COLORS_STATES, ... to set what is my reading state and consider by inputStream.read is a buffer ?
Or I miss a reader class ?
I fear to miss some bytes between 2 packets.
I'm a little disappointed about this, when I do it in java, I just write :

```
inputStream.read(numberOfBytes);
```

More easy to use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you have your RandomAccessFile open, you can do something like this:

```
RandomAccessFile raf; // Initialized elsewhere

int bufferSize = 1024*1024; // 1 MB
int offsetIntoFile = 0;
Uint8List byteBuffer = new Uint8List(bufferSize); // 1 MB
Future<int> bytesReadFuture = raf.readList(byteBuffer, offsetIntoFile, bufferSize);

bytesReadFuture.then((bytesRead) {
    Do something with byteBuffer here.
});
```

There is also a synchronous call readListSync.

John